# Camera starts to shaking when collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have problem in Unity. I have camera controller script. When you having collision with some object (wall, corner, terrain), it starts to shaking left-right. I don't know what to do, maybe problem in player body? please, help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(100, 250)] public float _sensetivity;
    [SerializeField] private float _xRotation;
    [SerializeField] private float _yRotation;

    [SerializeField] private Transform _playerBody;

    public void Awake()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
    public void LateUpdate()
    {

        float _mouseX = (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")) * _sensetivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float _mouseY = (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")) * _sensetivity * Time.deltaTime;

        _xRotation -= _mouseY;
        _yRotation -= _mouseX;

        _xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(_xRotation, -35, 35);

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(_xRotation, -_yRotation, 0);

        _playerBody.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -_yRotation, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I included a potential solution, but it might not work depending on your physics implementation; Would help to share the code to the player's movement, collision handling, or how rigidbodies/physics are setup in the inspector, etc.

Comment: regretfully, it don't soluting the problem. About the player controller, https://github.com/TheSanskrit/You-are-Game-Developer there's repository, you can look for it here

Comment: if his is using physics (due to the `collision`) like `Rigidbody` or `CharacterController` you shouldn't apply anything to the player via the `Transform` component ... is your camera a child of the player?

Comment: yes, camera is child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. I just made camera not child of player object, and made special child object of player, and assigning position of this object to camera.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution might be to smooth out the camera movement instead, using [Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html):

```
[SerializeField, Tooltip("Smoothing value, used when rotating the camera to match player's movement.")]
private float smoothingValue;

public void LateUpdate()
{
    float mouseX = (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")) * _sensetivity * Time.deltaTime;
    float mouseY = (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")) * _sensetivity * Time.deltaTime;

    _xRotation -= mouseY;
    _yRotation -= mouseX;

    _xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(_xRotation, -35, 35);

    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(_xRotation, -_yRotation, 0);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * smoothingValue);

    // NOTE: Might not be necessary to smooth out the player's rotation...?
    Quaternion playerTargetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -_yRotation, 0f);
    _playerBody.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(_playerBody.rotation, playerTargetRotation, Time.deltaTime * smoothin);
}
```